# How to Override CSS Settings from Dropdown Items of a Bootstrap NavBar Populated with vue.js Router

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, navbar, vue-router

I am using a Bootstrap NavBar populated with Vue.js Router as follows. I am trying to override some CSS settings of the drop-down items found in the b-dropdown-item element. How can I achieve this?

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" variant="white">
<b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
<b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
  <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">

    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Item" right>
      <b-dropdown-item id="dropitem" class="d-flex flex-column" href="#">
        <router-link class="d-block" v-for="routes in links"
        v-bind:key="routes.id"
        :to="`${routes.page}`">{{routes.text}}</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>

  </b-navbar-nav>
</b-collapse>
```

```
#dropitem {
 width:200px
}
```

Answer: It is possible to use an id on the element, as above (id="dropitem") to override some Bootstrap Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Open your console in the browser and find the tag html with the class containing the padding.

Once you have the class, you can rewrite the style of this class.

An other solution could be to apply a ng::deep class to the dropdown and set the padding to 0.